# IOS/Swift: Determine vertical position of last populated row of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview

I have a tableview on a screen where a keyboard appears and disappears.  If there are rows near the bottom that the keyboard would cover, I would like the tableview to move up just enough so that the rows are visible.

Right now, I can get the whole tableview to move up when the keyboard appears. This works because the tableview is constrained on the top and bottom all the way to the margins.

However, if there are only a few rows at the top, when the keyboard appears and pushes the tableview up, those rows are no longer visible.  SO I think I need to offset the tableview movement by the distance between the bottom row and the bottom of the tableview.

I can get the height of the keyboard using the following code:

```
 var heightKeyboard : CGFloat?
    func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let infoKey  = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey],
            let rawFrame = (infoKey as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
            let keyboardFrame = view.convert(rawFrame, from: nil)
            self.heightKeyboard = keyboardFrame.size.height
            // Now is stored in your heightKeyboard variable
        }
    }
```

However, I don't know how to get the coordinates of the bottom-most populated row of the tableview. (The tableview cells are self sizing based on content, so I can't just multiply the number of rows by a constant.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: What if you have a Double value declared as totalHeight, and every time you create a cell, in cellForRowAt method, you get the cell's height and add it to totalHeight by  totalHeight += cell.frame.height, and then where your keyboardWillShow method fires, you can check for that value if it's larger than a certain value you can do things differently in a manner. You might also wanna get the help of "tableView.visiblecells" maybe. Sorry Im not sure if these works, but just the ideas I had :)

Comment: Sounds like that might work.  But has a lot of manual steps.... Would be nice if there was some value maintained somewhere of the tableview size used...to be obtained somewhere like in didlayoutsubviews?

Comment: `UITableView visibleCells` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to change the `contentInset' property instead of the height of your tableView.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    CGRect rect = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat height = rect.size.height;

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, height, 0);
    NSInteger lastSection = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView] - 1;
    NSInteger lastRow = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection] - 1;
    NSIndexPath *lastRowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:lastSection];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastRowIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Tried this.  Whether the auto layout constraint on the tableview bottom is overriding the contenInset or some other reason, the keyboard still pushes the tableview up out of view when it appears.  The scrolling does not come into play if there are only a couple of cells in the tableview.

Comment: the code above works for me... so check your code/storyboard again

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

1. Call `addKeyboardObserver()` method from your `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` method.
2. Call `NotificationCenter.removeObserver(self)` method from your `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`.

`

```
func addKeyboardObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification){
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
            guard let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {return}
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height + padding, 0)
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification){
    guard let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {return}
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```